# Read network data from Airport Extreme

Tags: c, networking, snmp, dhcp

I'm making a network manager program as a small project, and I want it to be able to access data on my Airport Extreme (most importantly, the DHCP client list).

There has to be a way of accessing the client list file from the Airport Extreme, after all, Airport Utility can do it. All I want to do is read the data from the file/list.

If anyone could even point me in the right direction, that would be great. I'm also hoping that I can get this program to run on all *nix machines, not just a mac (so any Airport utility hacks wouldn't really help).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this via SNMP. Get hold of an SNMP browser such as GetIF and browse around the Airport via its address to see exactly what's in there, then use an SNMP library to get hold of the same information yourself in your application.

Network management essentially *is* SNMP. I'm surprised you hadn't come across it already.

Answer (score 1):

I can't leave a comment so I will leave an answer. I don't have a solid answer but I have a few bread crumbs that might be helpful.

see the comment on page 5 — https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5101886?start=60&tstart=0 by user "_r_s_"

Also

1) Open airport utility

2) Double click your airport device from the window or click the device and then click the edit button.

3) Now go to File>Export Configuration File

4) Open the .baseconfig file in your favorite editor

5) Now go to http://aldentech.wnyric.org/webshare/mkempste/AirPort%20Utility%20copy.app/Contents/Resources/English.lproj/AirPortSettings.strings to help you sort out what all the strings mean.

6) Edit your base config file — Use the site below to find out the strings meaning in the .baseconfig file and edit the file to yield the result you are looking for.

7) Import the file back to your airport device and it should give you the features it is capable of.

I am posting these steps because Apple has removed SNMP for Airport Utility but they appear to be in the XML.

If you are willing please leave a link to your project.